# Aligning top of tabular with surrounding text

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

How can a tabular environment with a top line be aligned with the surrounding text, so that no space is inserted above the top line of the tabular?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}

LEFT
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
  First
  &
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|} \hline
      Line & 1 \\ \hline
      Line & 2 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{tabular}
RIGHT

\end{document}
```

I want the top line of the tabular to be upper than what LaTeX is giving me. How can I get it aligned to the top of the surrounding text?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `\hline` command is causing the trouble. If you remove it, the table is aligned. If you want a horizontal line on top, use the `array`-package and the `\firsthline` command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

LEFT
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
First
&
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|} \firsthline
    Line & 1 \\ \hline
    Line & 2 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{tabular}
RIGHT

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have a way to tweak the `tabular` environment to fix that `hline` bug for `tabular[t]`?

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicemtrix`, you will have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

LEFT
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
First
&
    \begin{NiceTabular}[t]{|l|l|} \hline
    Line & 1 \\ \hline
    Line & 2 \\ \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}

\end{tabular}
RIGHT

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]